# Returning a match from a List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I currently have a class that uses the `KeyValuePair` with `List` to store a collection of tracks in the format of Key = track, Value = artist.

I'm trying to provide a way of searching for a particular track and if there are any matches then return the entire matching CD.

This is my attempt so far:

```
public CompilationCD FindTrackInComCD(string track)
{
    CompilationCD temp = new CompilationCD();

    List<CD> tempComCols = _cdCollection.FindAll(delegate(CD cd)
    { return cd.GetType() == temp.GetType(); });

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> comCD in tempComCols)
    {
        if (comCD.Key.Contains(track))
        {
            return comCD;
        }
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("No matches found");
}
```

I have a collection of Cd's of type CD (`List<CD>`) therefore I create a new `List<>` of the appropiate type by comparing it to the temp List.

When compiling I get the following errors:

```
Cannot convert type 'CDCollection.CD' to System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>'

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>'
```

(CDCollection is my project namespace and CD/CompilationCD are the classes)

Sorry for this seeming like a similar question to one I've previously asked. I tried to use the methods I was given before but I'm a bit stumped; I've not used `List<>` or `KeyValuePair` very often.

This is the CD Class:

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CDCollection
{
    public class CD
    {
        #region Fields
        private readonly string _artist;
        private readonly string _album;
        private List _track = new List();
        #endregion

```
    #region Constructors
    public CD()
    {
        _artist = "";
        _album = "";
        _track = null;
    }

    public CD(string albumName)
    {
        _album = albumName;
    }

    public CD(string artistName, string albumName)
    {
        _artist = artistName;
        _album = albumName;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Get/Set Artist Name
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Artist
    {
        get
        {
            return _artist;
        }
        set
        {
            value = _artist;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get/Set Album
    /// </summary>
    public string Album
    {
        get
        {
            return _album;
        }
        set
        {
            value = _album;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get/Set Track Name
    /// </summary>
    public virtual List<string> Track
    {
        get
        {
            return _track;
        }
        set
        {
            value = _track;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ToString()
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom ToString() Method
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        //Create new StringBuilder object
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("Artist Name");

        //Display error if Artist is not available
        if (_artist == null || _artist == "")
        {
            sb.Append("\nNo Artist Entered");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("\n" + this._artist);
        }

        sb.Append("\n");
        sb.Append("\nAlbum Name");

        //Display error if Album is not available
        if (_album == null || _album == "")
        {
            sb.Append("\nNo Album Entered");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("\n" + this._album);
        }

        sb.Append("\n");
        sb.Append("\nTrack Name");
        sb.Append("\n");

        //Iterate through all tracks stored in list
        foreach (string trackName in _track)
        {
            //Print each artist
            sb.Append("\n" + trackName);
        }

        sb.Append("\nEnd of CD Record.........");

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

This is the CompilationCD class:

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CDCollection
{
    public class CompilationCD : CD
    {
        #region Fields

```
    private readonly string _artist;
    private readonly string _album;
    private List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> _tracks = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();

    //List<KeyValuePair> Reference.
    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(VS.85).aspx

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public CompilationCD()
    {
        _album = "";
        _artist = "Various Artists";
    }

    public CompilationCD(string albumName):base(albumName)
    {
        _album = albumName;
        _artist = "Various Artists";
    }

    #endregion

    public void AddTracks(string track, string artist)
    {
        _tracks.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(track, artist));
    }

    #region Properties

    public override string Artist
    {
        get
        {
            return this._artist;
        }
    }

    public new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> Track
    {
        get
        {
            return _tracks;
        }
        set
        {
            _tracks = value;
        }
    }


    #endregion

    #region ToString()

    //TEST
    public override string ToString()
    {
        //Create new StringBuilder object
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("Artist Name");

        //Display error if Artist is not available
        if (_artist == null || _artist == "")
        {
            sb.Append("\nNo Artist Entered");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("\n" + this._artist);
        }

        sb.Append("\n");
        sb.Append("\nAlbum Name");

        //Display error if Album is not available
        if (base.Album == null || base.Album == "")
        {
            sb.Append("\nNo Album Entered");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("\n" + base.Album);
        }

        sb.Append("\n");
        sb.Append("\nTrack Name");
        sb.Append("\n");

        ////Iterate through all tracks stored in list
        //foreach (string trackName in base.Track)
        //{
        //    //Print each artist
        //    sb.Append("\n" + trackName);
        //}

        for(int i = 0; i <= _tracks.Count; i++)
        {
            string track = _tracks[i].Key;
            string artist = _tracks[i].Value;

            sb.Append("\nTrack");
            sb.Append(track);
            sb.Append("\nArtist");
            sb.Append(artist);
        }

        sb.Append("\nEnd of Compilation CD Record.........");

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

I have strict rules that mean i have to inherit from CD to create my CompilationCD as well as using a List> for my track collection, it needs to hold both a track and artist. Crazy i know =/

Furthermore i must store ALL types of cd in a list of type CD ( List ).

Comment: You should consider using operator `is` instead of comparing the return values of `GetType()`. It's both faster, shorter, and plays better with extensibility (e.g. if you later derive some class from `CompilationCD`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `foreach` loop.  `tempComCols` is a `List<CD>`, but `comCD` is a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.  So, your loop results in an invalid type conversion.

Unfortunately, since we don't know what the `CD` class (interface?) looks like, I can't suggest a fix in terms of its properties.

**EDIT:** The following is perhaps a better version of your method (though, I haven't debugged it correctly):

```
public CompilationCD FindTrackInComCD(string track)
{
    CompilationCD temp = new CompilationCD();

    temp = _cdCollection.Where(cd => cd is CompilationCD)
                        .Cast<CompilationCD>()
                        .Where(com_cd => com_cd.Tracks.ContainsKey(track))
                        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (temp != null)
        return temp;
    else throw new ArgumentException("No matches found");
}
```

You can't cast a `CompilationCD` to a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`, so we just use the `CompilationCD` class directly.  We can pass off the responsibility for searching the track list to the `IEnumerable<T>` extenion methods provided by `System.Linq`, which makes this method very easy.

Comment: I've added the classes for the CD and CompilationCD =]

Comment: Which version of the .Net framework are you using?  There are differences in the "standard" idiom based on whether LINQ is available or not.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use a dictionary? They are a list of key value pairs, but provide easy access via the key.

Comment: After trying to implement the dictionary it turns out there's a chance of it breaking too much.

Comment: What do you mean, "breaking"? Care to elaborate?

Comment: My program was designed in pairs, my partner has done their own contribution but didn't leave much to be changed without the majority of the entire application being changed.

Comment: Well, I think a dictionary is your best bet. You might as well do the refactoring to clean things up.

Comment: Okay, how would i access the Key and Value through the properties if i store the dictionary in a List<> ?

Answer (score 0):

that's because `tempComCols` will return `CD` and not `KeyValuePair<string, string>`

Answer (score 0):

Your `List` doesn't contain `KeyValuePairs`, so you can't loop through it as if it did. Try something like this:

```
foreach (CD comCD in tempComCols)
{
    if (comCD.MyKeyValueProp.Key.Contains(track))
    {
        return comCD;
    }
}
```

But as McKay said, if your `CD` class does nothing but encapsulate a `KeyValuePair`, a `Dictionary` would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

tempComCols is list of `CD` items: `List<CD> tempComCols ...` and you want to iterate over something that is of type IEnumerable: `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> comCD in tempComCols)`

Answer (score 0):

You are enumerating a `List<CD>` and assigning to a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

You can rewrite your method using LINQ in C# 3 like this:

```
public CompilationCD FindTrackInComCD(string track) {
    return _cdCollection.OfType<CompilationCD>().FirstOrDefault(cd => cd.Name.Contains(track, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

By the way, you can get the `System.Type` object for `CompilationCD` by writing `typeof(CompilationCD)`; you don't need to call `GetType()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use:

   ```
   {cd is CompilationCD};
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   { return cd.GetType() == temp.GetType(); });
   ```
2. if I understand correctly and CD is some sort of Dictionary, you can rewrite the function as:

   ```
   public CompilationCD FindTrackInComCD(string track)
   {
       return (CompilationCD)_cdCollection.Find(delegate(CD cd)
       { return (cd is CompilationCD) && (cd.Contains(track))});
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use KeyedCollection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx